# fastest way to check for a node being connected to n properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Right now I have a loop generating my distance, but it seems like their could be a more efficient way

```
taglst = ['term1', 'term2', 'term3', 'term4', 'term5']
for i, each in enumerate(taglst):
    word = 'dist'+str(i)
    if i == 0:
        q += "MATCH p-[r]-(g {name:\'%s\'}) WITH p, r.dist as %s " %    (each, word)
    else:
        temp = 'dist'+str(i-1)
        q += "MATCH p-[r]-(g {name:\'%s\'}) WITH p, r.dist + %s as %s " %(each, temp, word)
 q += "RETURN p ORDER by %s ASC" %(word)
```

Any theories or ideas to help would be great, I'm not really concerned with the python just wanted to demonstrate the workflow for the cypher query.

Comment: I can't quite figure out what you're trying to do here.  What is `r.dist`?  You don't initialize `q` what is it?  What kind of node is `g`?  What is `p`?

Comment: sorry you're right its pretty convoluted.  Their are p is the set of nodes I'm trying to find, g represents the tags.  So I want all p that are connected to all of g.

Comment: dist is a parameter that is the distance from the node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there should be an easier way.  Try this:

```
MATCH (p)-[r]-(g) 
WITH p, r, collect(g) as gNodes
WHERE ALL (gNode in gNodes WHERE gNode.name in ['term1', 'term2', 'term3'])
RETURN p ORDER BY r.something ASC
```

You will need to tailor this, but the way it works is by checking that all possible `g` nodes have a name that's in your list.   This saves you repetitive matching the way you've structured it now.

**however** -- you haven't provided enough information to make this query really good.  As I've formulated this, it's going to be expensive because there are no constraints on `(p)-[r]-(g)`.  Something that vague is a formula to match your entire graph.   Much better would be if you put an initial criteria on `r` or `p` to narrow things down drastically.

Comment: I had a query like this before MATCH (p:Album)<-[r]-(tags)

        WHERE tags.name IN %s
        WITH p, COLLECT(tags) as tags, SUM(toFloat(r.dist)) as dist
        WHERE LENGTH(tags) = LENGTH(%s)
        RETURN p ORDER BY dist ASC LIMIT 11; 

and it was pretty slow but I'll try using the collect statement first

Comment: Use a label designator on tags, that will help -- but still the way this is being formulated, you're matching all album/tag pairings, if you have a lot of albums, that's just a lot.

Comment: ya I just figured my way would help to limit because it would slowly shave off slices instead of grouping everything first.  I see your point though.